# Silverlight behavior databinding

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm following [this](http://www.dansoltesz.com/post/2011/07/29/silverlight-listbox-autoscroll-behavior.aspx) example for an auto-scrolling behavior on a ListBox on WP7 Mango RC targeting 7.1.

In my Xaml:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="StatusMessages"
                 Height="100"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding StatusMessages, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Message"
                 Grid.Row="3">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:ListBoxItemAutoScrollBehavior FoundItem="{Binding FoundItem}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListBox>
```

The behavior:

```
 public class ListBoxItemAutoScrollBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
    {       
        public object FoundItem
        {
            get { return GetValue(FoundItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FoundItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FoundItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FoundItem", typeof (object), typeof (ListBoxItemAutoScrollBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(FoundItemChanged));

        private static void FoundItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ListBoxItemAutoScrollBehavior) d).AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(e.NewValue);
        }
    }
```

I have a breakpoint set at the FoundItemChanged method and would expect to see it hit when I set FoundItem in my ViewModel and fire NotifyProperyChanged.  Only, it doesn't work, any ideas why or what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

**update**: breakpoints are hit for OnAttached and OnDetaching in the behavior.

**update** 2: This works in a regular Silveright 4 application.

**update** 3: Using version 3.8.5.0 of System.Windows.Interactivity fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using version 3.8.5.0 of System.Windows.Interactivity fixed this problem.

This post gave me the tip: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/271092

Answer (score 2):

Are you targeting 7.1 / Mango? Binding to DependencyObjects, as opposed to FrameworkElements, is a Silverlight 4 feature and thus not available in 7.0 (which uses SL 3).

There's a workaround that Prism and MVVM Light use to bind to DO's in SL 3. Check out their source for details.

*Edit:* Your problem is your PropertyMetadata constructor arguments. By not specifying 2 arguments (or, specifically, passing a method rather than a PropertyChangedCallback instance), the compiler might be resolving the [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557329%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) constructor overload.

In short, change it to:

```
new PropertyMetadata(null, FoundItemChanged)
```

Or:

```
new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(FoundItemChanged))
```

Comment: @Derek - I think I may have sussed it, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Richard but it still doesn't work.  Its not critical for me to get this working but I'd really like to see it work for sanity sake.

Comment: @Derek If the first or the two snippets didn't work then I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions, other than to create a simpler behavior with a working binding and work backwards from there.

Comment: Yeah, I've made it really simple now.  One note, if I set FoundItem="test" instead of FoundItem={Binding FoundItem, Mode=TwoWay} the breakpoint in the setter gets hit.  When its bound it doesn't.

Comment: @Derek - On a probably unrelated note, I'd recommend removing `Mode=TwoWay` from both the bindings above. At best, it's dead code that can be removed; at worst, it could be affecting the bug you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, TwoWay wouldn't be needed, I've removed it from the code above, tried it several ways though.  Maybe this is a bug with mango since it works fine in SL4.  Upvoted your answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: Using version 3.8.5.0 of System.Windows.Interactivity fixed it :|

Comment: @Derek - You should post that as it's own answer.